# Bluetooth module with lowest latency to communicate with PC

Tags: wifi, bluetooth, ethernet, hc-05, latency

I am making a haptic feedback glove using Arduino and HC-05 bluetooth module to communicate with PC.

There are rotary encoders on the finger which send value to PC through Arduino mega. The PC returns the force to be excerted on the finger back to Arduino which then controls the motor. The communication between Arduino and PC is established through an HC-05 module wired to Arduino and connected to PC wirelessly over bluetooth. Through COM-Port of Arduino-IDE, serial communication is established.

When the program runs, the PC (Unity) sends the force to Arduino but there is a huge latency in the order of tens of milliseconds. After Unity calculates the force, Arduino receives this force after at least 30ms (I have not measured the accurate value). In order to make sure the delay is a result of bluetooth communication, I connected the Arduino to PC using USB and the latency was reduced. This points to the fact that the delay is caused by the bluetooth.

I did some research into that and found that there is something called BLE as opposed to classic bluetooth which decreases the delay. According to this [link](https://iotlab.tertiumcloud.com/2020/08/19/classic-bluetooth-vs-bluetooth-low-energy-ble/), HC-05 which uses classic bluetooth has a latency of 100ms and BLE has a latency of 6ms.

I want to buy a bluetooth module that has BLE capability like HM-10. Before that, I wanted to know if I have understood the information correctly: i.e buying an HM-10 would decrease communication gap. Is there any alternatives to bluetooth communication (such as ethernet or wifi) which would provide low or lower latency?